# Prevent Folder Deletion in Git BitBucket

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

I have a PHP project and am using BitBucket for repository. I have a folder which stores images that are used by part of a application and these images are created dynamically. Now I wanted to clean my local copy of this folder and hence deleted all images from my local machine. I committed the delete of the images on this folder not knowing that commit of image deletion on my local machine will end up deleting the folder itself on my server.

I was assuming that this will only delete those images which were generated on my local machine and which I had checked in earlier.

```
So 1) Why did emptying my folder end up deleting the folder itself on the server 
2) How do I prevent this folder being deleted next time inadvertently in the same why I did
```

Comment: Cant you revert the commit?

Answer (score 4):

git doesn't keep empty folders (at least by default), so when you delete all the files, it considers the folder as non-existent. An easy solution is to put a dummy file in it (like an empty .gitignore), but a more semantic way is to place an empty file called **.gitkeep** . This way it is treated as a git file (matches .git* pattern) plus all the teamworkers will understand why that file is there.

Comment: thanks. You said at least by default so is there a way to override this setting?

Comment: no, there is not - git only cares about files and sees directories merely as a hierarchy, in which files exist. You do not have to call it .gitkeep for that matter, but can add any filename to create a folder. On your specific problem: simply add a check for the required folder in your bootstrapping process and try an mkdir of the required folder. Much easier for the enduser.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of commit don't use `git add .` it will take all changes change you can add specific file suppose `git add hello.py` this will not affect on other files. Source [Git Tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-add)